# Django Add Q filters to query when related object exists, Conditional query

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I am triying to query my product model like this:

- I have Product model that is related to an user
- My user can have a related Store, and its store can be unactive or no-visible

So, my products can be sold by an user that has a store or an user that **not has** a store; what I want to do is to make query adding these extra parameters when **"has_store"** condition beign True like this.

```
   store_query = ({"seller__user_store__is_active": True,
                  "seller__user_store__is_visible": True}
                 if F("seller__user_store__isnull=False") else {})
```

And then add that query to my filtering sentence:

```
   Product.objects.filter(Q(is_new=True) & Q(is_active=True), **store_query)
```

My product model also has **is_new**, and **is_active** and other parameters.
So, expected behaviour is something like add `Q(seller__user_store__is_visible=True)` and `Q(seller__user_store__is_active=True)` if product seller has a related store

I hope have been clear, thanks you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you make things too complicated. The `stored_query` is just equivalent to:

```
Q(seller__user_store=None) | Q(seller__user_store__is_active=True, seller__user_store__is_visible=True)
```

Indeed, in case the `seller__user_store=None`, it does not have to look to the conditions of the seller, otherwise it will. We can thus implement this as:

```
Product.objects.filter(
    Q(seller__user_store=None) | Q(seller__user_store__is_active=True, seller__user_store__is_visible=True),
    is_new=True, is_active=True
)
```